# Checking table properties (i.e. size) with JPA

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, orm

I am using JPA to do ORM. However, one thing I'd particularly like to do is to also be able to check the size of the tables that are being managed. Are there any streamlined ways of doing it or do I need to keep a set of separate JDBC scripts to do the more conventional DB management stuff?

Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I accepted what I could. The rest are largely answers that weren't real solutions.

Comment: Understood and thanks. This should bump the topic, hopefully you get a good answer; I wish I could help you with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What size? you mean number of rows ? which you can obviously get with "SELECT COUNT(p) FROM Person p". JPA doesn't do physical size of a datastore, so you'd have to have some native queries to get that (datastore specific also).

Comment: Good to know. So that means it's a general practice to keep a library of native JDBC scripts AND an ORM package?

Comment: Wouldn't say general practice; some organisations will have DBAs to look after native stuff, and app developers will use their API for what their app requires at runtime

Comment: What kind of DBA's for instance? While I don't really need that for the moment since I already wrote my packages, I am always looking for newer and more efficient ways to manage code.

Comment: By "DBA" I mean a person ("database administrator") whose sole focus is on the DB, storage space, and having it running efficiently.

Comment: Ah ok. Meaning the division of task between different parties nullifies this requirement.